# How to get a summary using only SQL from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
Table posts
    post_id
    category_id
    title

Table visits
    visit_id
    post_id
    visit_date

Table categories
    category_id
    category_name
```

I need to get something like this (assuming that table visits has 10 rows)

```
Category 1 (categories.category_name) / visits(count) = 5
Category 2 (categories.category_name) / visits(count) = 1
Category 3 (categories.category_name) / visits(count) = 4
```

How can I get a similar result using only MySQL?

I tried with INNERs, no success

Comment: Did you try to join the tables?

Comment: @forpas  I tried it, but Im doing something bad, got an error.

Comment: Post your code and the error you get.

Comment: @forpas I'm trying first directly in MySQL, I don't know how to get a group (table post.category_id) and a count (table visits) and category data (from table categories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple query. You need to join all three tables, and finally group the result by category name. It should look like:

```
select
  c.category_name, 
  count(*)
from categories c
join posts p on p.categoryid = c.category_id
join visits v on v.post_id = p.post_id
group by c.category_name
order by c.category_name
```